# Postgres on AWS performance issues on filter or aggregate

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-performance

I'm working on a system which has a table with aprox. 13 million records.
It does not appear to be big deal for postgres, but i'm facing serious performance issues when hitting this particular table.

The table has aprox. 60 columns (I know it's too much, but I can't change it for reasons beyond my will).

Hardware ain't problem. It's running on AWS. I tested several configurations, even the new RDS for postgres:

```
                             vCPU   ECU     mem(gb) 

m1.xlarge        64 bits     4      8       15

m2.xlarge        64 bits     2      6,5     17  

hs1.8xlarge      64 bits     16     35      117       SSD
```

I tuned pg settings with pgtune. And also set the ubuntu's kernel sshmall and shmmax.

Some "explain analyze" queries:

select count(*) from:

```
$Aggregate  (cost=350390.93..350390.94 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=24864.287..24864.288 rows=1 loops=1)
    ->  Index Only Scan using core_eleitor_sexo on core_eleitor  (cost=0.00..319722.17 rows=12267505 width=0) (actual time=0.019..12805.292 rows=12267505 loops=1)
    Heap Fetches: 9676
Total runtime: 24864.325 ms
```

select distinct core_eleitor_city from:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=159341.37..159341.39 rows=2 width=516) (actual time=15965.740..15966.090 rows=329 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on core_eleitor  (cost=1433.53..159188.03 rows=61338 width=516) (actual time=956.590..9021.457 rows=5886110 loops=1)
    Recheck Cond: ((core_eleitor_city)::text = 'RIO DE JANEIRO'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on core_eleitor_city  (cost=0.00..1418.19 rows=61338 width=0) (actual time=827.473..827.473 rows=5886110 loops=1)
       Index Cond: ((core_eleitor_city)::text = 'RIO DE JANEIRO'::text)
Total runtime: 15977.460 ms
```

I have btree indexes on columns frequently used for filter or aggregations.

So, given I can't change my table design. Is there something I can do to improve the performance?

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're aggregating ~12.3M and ~5.9M rows on a VPS cluster that, if I am not mistaking, might span multiple physical servers, with data that is probably pulled from a SAN on yet another set of different server than Postgres itself.

Imho, there's little you can do to make it faster on (AWS anyway), besides a) not running queries that basically visit the entire database table to begin with and b) maintaining a pre-count using triggers if possible if you persist in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go for improving the performance on RDS:

As referred to link here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html

Amazon RDS uses MySQL’s built-in replication functionality to create a special type of DB instance called a read replica from a source DB instance. Updates made to the source DB instance are copied to the read replica. You can reduce the load on your source DB instance by routing read queries from your applications to the read replica. Read replicas allow you to elastically scale out beyond the capacity constraints of a single DB instance for read-heavy database workloads.

Comment: Note: The OP was referring to Postgres, which has no read replica capabilities on RDS yet.